# How do I eliminate Group By successfully?

Tags: group-by

When I run the below query I get a single-line result with 238 "gifts." How do I query to return 238 LINES so that I can see the revenue associated with EACH gift?  I tried to eliminate Group By but then it gets angry and says my selects don't make sense (Error: "Column 'campcode.campcode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.").

```
select
c2.campcode,
substring(s1.source,1,6) as Package,
p.descrip as Panel,
pc.packcode,
pc.descrip,
COUNT(m1.names_id) as Mailed,
SUM(case when s1.numbermail=0 then 0 else (s1.acost/s1.numbermail) end) as Cost,
COUNT(c1.camt) as Gifts,
SUM(c1.camt) as Income


from mailing    m1 
left join source    s1 with (nolock) on m1.source_key=s1.source_key
left join campcode c2 with (nolock) on s1.camp_key=c2.camp_key
left join packcode pc with (nolock) on pc.pack_key=s1.pack_key
left join panelcode p with (nolock) on p.panel_key = s1.panel_key
left join contrib c1 with (nolock) on m1.source_key = c1.source_key and 
m1.names_id = c1.names_id 
and     c1.moneytype <> -1            
and     c1.type <> 6  
and     c1.camt >0

where       c2.campcode like '18D9Y'   
and substring(s1.source,1,6) like '18D9YC' 
and     c1.cdate between '2017-09-01' and '2018-04-23'

group by    
c2.campcode,
substring(s1.source,1,6),
p.descrip,
pc.packcode,
pc.descrip
```